# alternately linux script via Cron job

Tags: bash, cron, devops

I need to run two scripts alternately (day yes and day no)via cron jobs, as example today the first script will run so tomorrow the second script will run and the first script will be stopped And so on
.

Comment: why dont you just schedule 2 cronjobs? whats the problem?

Comment: Basically https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16093/how-can-i-tell-cron-to-run-a-command-every-other-day-odd-even

Comment: Does this also have to work reliably across month and year changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run script every day, then write a wrapper that will select every second day:

```
0 0 * * * wrapper.sh
```

```
# wrapper.sh
#!/bin/bash
days_since_epoch=$(( $(date +%s)/3600/24 ))
if (( days_since_epoch % 2 )); then
    ./script1
else
    ./script2
fi
```